# set iPhone Required device capabilities

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

My application is for "iPhone ONLY", But I have made a mistake in the first place by not setting the application for specific device.

The current setting now is:
Requirement: Compatible for iPhone, iPod touch and iPad.

I would like to set it to:
Requirement: Compatible for iPhone.

I have go to some tutorial and forum. and nothing can solve my problem. I have also contact the apple support and this is what I got:

"You are permitted to expand your device requirements only.  Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your device requirements is not permitted. "

is it mean that I can not set my application for iPhone only?

If i can change it, what would you recommend me to do?

I have change the setting of device capability inside the plist, to one of this. which one is correct, use "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" or "Required device capabilities"?

i provide the screenshoot in here:
http://img218.imageshack.us/gal.php?g=screenshot20100604atam1.png

does the way I use it correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "You are permitted to expand your device requirements only. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your device requirements is not permitted. "

I think you have posted the answer yourself. As of now, it looks like you cannot change it